# as it stands/as it is

Tags: pronouns, reference

What does "it" in "as it stands" and "as it is now" refer to? The situation or the evidence?

> The evidence, as **it** stands, cannot be conclusive.
>
> The evidence, as **it** is now, cannot be conclusive.

The following sentence seems to suggest "it" refers to the general situation:

> As **it** stands, we are over budget, and we can't continue until we get more money."

Answer (score 2):

The first 2 examples have already specified **"The evidence"** so **"it"** refers to the evidence. In the third example there is nothing to qualify what **"it"** is so the meaning must be inferred from the context, in this case it is generally accepted that **"it"** refers to the current situation.

You could avoid this wording by saying

> The current evidence is inconclusive

and

> Currently we are over budget ...

Comment: Since the current situation is a broad concept, it can involve the evidence itself. I am wondering whether "as it stands" in the OP can also refer to the general situation, considering the ambiguity of the phrase. Maybe it's a less likely interpretation, but being less likely is not equal to being wrong.

Comment: You may have a point and others could agree with you, but in my experience **The evidence** defines / restricts what **it** refers to. And even the 3rd example needs some context as, on its own, **it** is highly ambiguous, it could be anything taken in isolation. It is the sort of sentence the might crop up during a meeting about, say, a specific project.